# Enforce a type only on defined members of an object, without widening the 'keysof typeof [object]' to string[]?

Tags: typescript, object, type-inference, typeof

So I've created a type:

```
type Status = {
    name: string,
    description: string,
    statusLightColor: string
}
```

And I've got an object whose members I want to be of type `Status`

```
const ListOfStatuses = {
    not_started: {name: "Not Started", description: "The work has not started.", statusLightColor: "Red"},
    in_progress: {name: "In Progress", description: "The task is currently in progress and will be complete soon.", statusLightColor: "Yellow"},
    is_finished: {name: "Is Finished", description: "The work is finished.", statusLightColor: "Green"},
}
```

And finally I've got another type which I want to **limit to the keys of** `ListOfStatuses`. So I do this:

```
type StatusID = keyof typeof ListOfStatuses
```

And magically, it totally works because typescript is creating an inference type whose indexes are limited to the keys of `ListOfStatuses`, and my IDE shows `type StatusID = "not_started" | "in_progress" | "is_finished"`

## **But here's the problem**

In order for this to work, I've had to intentionally not define the type of `ListOfStatuses` so TypeScript can infer it. But now, if I wanted to add another Status to `ListOfStatuses` and I wasn't careful, **TS would not enforce the type Status upon members of ListOfStatuses**.

If I define the type like so: `const ListOfStatuses : { [x: string]: Status } = {...}`, type is enforced but now `StatusID` breaks and widens as: `type StatusID = string | number`.

**How can I enforce the type `Status` upon members of `ListOfStatuses` without widening the type of its keys?**

## **Why I want to do this:**

The purpose of the type `StatusID` is to create a lightweight reference to a `Status` object which holds more detailed information, since there will only ever be (in this case) 3 valid Statuses, and there will be many objects which need a defined status, which will be sent back and forth over the network.

Following best practices to reduce repetition, I wanted to create a solution that allowed me or a future developer to only edit a single object within the codebase to add or remove Statuses.

I thought about using an interface for `ListOfStatuses` but I'm not sure how to readily access its values in other parts of the codebase. Additionally (I'm not sure if this is relevant), I'd like to avoid using a function call to fetch a `Status` object because I'm not sure if it will play well with Angular's change detection when used with binding.

This is a solution that I've come up with, but it's rather inelegant because you still have to edit two different things, although at least it throws a compile error if the `ListOfStatuses` and `StatusID` are mismatched.

```
type StatusID = 'not_started' | 'in_progress' | 'is_finished';
const ListOfStatuses: { [key in StatusID]: Status } = {...}
```

Obviously it's not that much of a hassle to update both in this example, but it could get annoying in a list of many more objects, and I'd like to streamline the process of modifying details of the codebase for myself and other devs in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would recommend using `[key: string]: Status` since if you add/remove a status later on, it could break unrelated parts which depended on hard coded properties rather than iterating over members.

Although there is a solution to this problem using temporary variables, though this could be hidden with an inline function.

```
type Status = {
    name: string,
    description: string,
    statusLightColor: string
}

const temp = {
  not_started: {
    // name: "Not Started",
    description: "The work has not started.",
    statusLightColor: "Red"
  },
  in_progress: { name: "In Progress", description: "The task is currently in progress and will be complete soon.", statusLightColor: "Yellow" },
  is_finished: { name: "Is Finished", description: "The work is finished.", statusLightColor: "Green" },
};

const ListOfStatuses: {
  [key in keyof typeof temp]: Status
} = temp; // This now throws an error that TS cannot convert from typeof temp to Status.
```

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!